# Struggling with Threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm newbie at C#, and I'm struggling with Threading(maybe).

When I start debugging, and execute one by one, ...and loading form is completed, procedure is placed at strange position like this :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (args.Length > 0)
            Application.Run(new frmMain(args[1]));
        else
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
    } // Stops here
```

I suspected it is normal, so I created new project and executed. and result was different with before like this:

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1()); // Stops here
        }
```

Now I'm very confused, So I need a help. someone tell me it is threading, but I didn't used any threading in my code.

- P.S.  I used NAudio Library to play music so I declared on frmMain class like this:

  ```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using NAudio;
    using NAudio.Wave;
    using TagLib;
    (...)
    AudioFileReader _audioFileReader;
    IWavePlayer _waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
    (...)
  ```
- P.S. 2 ..And this is constructor of frmMain.

  ```
      InitializeComponent();

      this.listMusic.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(this.FileDragOver);
      this.listMusic.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.FileDragDrop);
      this.listMusic.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(this.listDoubleClick);

      _waveOutDevice.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(this.PlaybackStopped);
  ```

Comment: Please don't link to external images. It severely affects the quantity and quality of answers you'll get. Can you please inline the images in your question?

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about that. sorry. I'll edit right now.

Comment: I edited about that, but editor says I need 10 reputation to attach images. So I replaced with codes.

Comment: A happy coincidence, then: code is better than images of code.

Comment: Does the application close on its on when you run it, put a break point within the main form constructor also.

Comment: application does not closed, but some cross-thread error occured when calling some functions.

Comment: Whats the error? when you start (F5) without debugging whats the result? Do you mean the code control (yellow line highlight) halts where you wrote *stops here*. We need to understand this problem better to answer. Please elaborate.

Comment: hmmm... I need to question again more detail. I'm sorry.

Comment: Have you the details of the Cross thread error(s)? This type of error generally occurs when Form controls are updated in a secondary thread. You may set _form1.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false_. But it is  not recommended.

Comment: I tried, but that made the program halt.

Comment: Funny title. I just expected something like: "Struggling with Threading? Buy our new Easy-Thread-Pal(tm) and all your nasty multi threading problems are gone! Call now and get Easy-Thread-Pal(tm) today ..." Sorry, this wasn't very helpful.

Comment: There is no code here that should cause the problems you are showing. You need to give us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org). If you do this, its likely you will find the problem on your own.

Comment: We need to see your entire `frmMain` constructor implementation, the exception and callstack for the error you are getting. Also, are you doing anything in your form `Load` event? From what you have shown, there isn't anything wrong.

Answer (score -2):

It could be that another part of the code is using multiple threads.  I've had situations where there were multiple threads and as I single-stepped through code, the current location bounces around.  It's not really a problem as long as you understand what it's doing, but if you halt execution in the debugger, it can stop somewhere you don't expect.

If you want to stop execution in your code, place breakpoints (F9) on lines of your code, then, when you've started an operation that enters your code, step through as desired.

If you're curious about what other threads are running, there is the Threads window; while debugging, go to the Debug window, select Windows, then Threads.  If you're not creating threads of your own, it may or may not be useful, but sometimes it's handy to see what might be loaded when you pause execution in the debugger.

Comment: This is not true. WinForms by default will do everything on the UI thread, which is a SINGLE thread.